# i am getting a red cross on the APP button

Tags: android

Recently, i have downloaded android studio, in that i saw a cross mark on the APP button. And when i run it, although the emulator appears but, it only shows the google sign, that's it. It doesn't shows my code. Should i update my kotlin version. i have tried all the ways like sync project with gradle files etc.(the picture)[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9x7P.png)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vr6V.png)

how should i fix it?

Comment: How long did you wait? The emulator can take some time (a few minutes) to start up.

Comment: well, after i click the run button although, the emulator is running,  but it shows only the google sign and at the beginning there is no red cross mark on the APP button, but when i click the run button, automatically, the red cross will appear on the APP button.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to check your Manifests file -> Merged Manifest. (Check if any error occur and resolve it)

Comment: like there are errors mainActivity, but it shows under the layout one( import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import au.com.itview.shell.R

class MainActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
})

Answer (score 0):

- Click on that **App** button
- Choose **Edit Configurations...**
- Select **Android App** / **app** in left menu
- Look for **Launch Options** in tab **General** in right menu
- Change it into **Nothing**
- Apply and waiting...

Comment: well, nothing happens still. i even waited for 5-10 mins, but still, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The red X is there saying you cannot build/run your project because it had an error while indexing your application. Sometimes that error occurs when you open a project. All it needs to do is index your code again.